# Displaying highchart columnrange charting xAxis, yAxis and series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have columnrange charting . I am trying to display xaxsis ,yAxsis and series data on the chart . But somehow i can't display all the categories on yAxis and xAxsis on the chart from the data  and i can't display series ,too . This code was working for linechart and updated couple of thing in the code to modify it to columnrange charting but no luck .

I am pushing the data in an array `var series = [];` and call it in series but doesn't display anything

I saved it in jfiddle since the script is long

Here is the link

Thanks  http://jsfiddle.net/a7rmx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors:

- trying to attach series to data, shoule be: `series: series`
- wrong format for points, should be: `{ low: from, high: to, x: x }`

See fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rmx/45/

Comment: You need to get them from your JSON and set as categories.. http://jsfiddle.net/a7rmx/46/

Comment: I have one more question here . if you have time please help.Thanks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130685/high-chart-displaying-marker-symbol-on-column-range-datalabels