# High chart - displaying marker symbol on column range dataLabels

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a column range charting and it works fine . I just want to display marker symbol on top and bottom for each dataLabels and make string among this symbols. I tried to use

```
marker:{ 
 enabled :true}
```

but it didn't work

here's the jsfiddlle

http://jsfiddle.net/7eurU/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column series doesn't have marker for columns. You can add serparate series (scatter) for each value.

Or try to develop some plugin to add this, like this one: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/2/Trackball (it's adding marker only on mouse over, but the idea is the same).

Comment: I update this one var item = {name: task.name,data: [],type:'columnrange'}; and it worked as column range. But i couln't achieve it with the series

Comment: Can you help me on that ? I added new series in plot options and also series itself but no result

Comment: Not in plotOptions, add series the same way you have added first one.. anyway, another solution with renderer: http://jsfiddle.net/88DYg/6/. Seriously, adding scatter series is much easier than this solution.

Comment: I tried to add it , but i couldn't achieve it . thats why i asked you. I am gonna work on this . hope it helps me.Thanks Pawel

Comment: Here is another question , you may interested  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274699/highcharts-using-flag-in-columnrange-charting-to-make-a-datarange-invisible-an     Thanks