# Highcharts - using flag in columnrange charting to make a datarange invisible and dispaly message

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have highcharts - columnrange chart which works fine but I want to make invisible one of the  dataranges based on a data.

For example in my code:
 `var arylist = '[{"name" :"taxupdt_ftp","st_time_am_pm" :"n/a","ed_time_am_pm" :" pm",`

When `"st_time_am_pm" :"n/a"` is this I want to disable that data range and display message says "not available".

[here is JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pq5eG/)

Thanks. Any help appreciates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set parameter visible as false and then in the callback hide a point graphic.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pq5eG/1/

```
   $.each(chart.series, function(i, s){
        $.each(s.data, function(j, p){
               if(p.hidden)
                   p.graphic.hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: how can i display message  says " not available "

Comment: and what is this  thing ??      series[7].data[0].y = null;  it is hardcoded . i need to handle real data which comes from arrylist .

Comment: You can remove it, sorry for my mess ;D

Answer (score 0):

It should be running with the real data .   so  series:series should be stay there . you shouldn't add dumb data in series . Because data already coming from var arrylist ,

I tried a way which looked logical to me but it is not working

```
  item.data.push({
            x: i,
            label: interval.label,
            low: interval.from,
            hidden:true,
            high: interval.to,
            color: "blue"
                        });
```

@Sebastian , can you look into this by replacing this in the fist condition.